# OOP duplicate extends

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes which both extend from SQL class

like this:

```
class SQL {  
    private $db_connect_id;  
    function connect($ad, $db, $us, $pa){  
        $this->db_connect_id = mssql_connect($ad, $us, $pa);  
        mssql_select_db ($db, $this->db_connect_id) or die('sql error');  
    }  
    function sql_query($query = ""){  
        unset($this->query_result);  
        if($query != ""){  
            $this->num_queries++;  
            $this->query_result = @mssql_query($query, $this->db_connect_id) or die('error query');  
        }  
        if($this->query_result){  
            unset($this->row[$this->query_result]);  
            unset($this->rowset[$this->query_result]);  
            return $this->query_result;  
        }  
    }   
}

class WEB extends SQL {  
    function __construct(){ $this->connect(params) }  
    function __destruct(){ $this->disconnect() }  
}

class AUTH extends SQL {  
    function __construct(){ $this->connect(params) }  
    function __destruct(){ $this->disconnect() }  
}
```

the problem is that if I call both of them

```
$WEB = new WEB();  
$AUTH = new AUTH();
```

the `$WEB` won't work anymore. It loses its connection with the database and it changes the db_connect_id with the db_connect_id from AUTH...
I think this is a stupid question and I'm too tired, but I have to finish.
Where I'm doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

There is fourth param `new_link` that must be passed as `true` (because default is `false`).

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to tell from the limited code you've posted, but I think it's pretty clear that you have some singleton-like behavior going on i.e., all instances of `SQL` and its subclasses are sharing references.

Maybe if you replaced `bla bla` with the actual code we could narrow it down for you.

Comment: If you have other methods that run stuff like `mysql_query` make sure they use `$this->db_connect_id`

Comment: the mssql_query is made by a function in the SQL class, and it uses $this->db_connect_id

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code as presented in your question.

The problem you are describing is symptomatic of using a static property of the SQL class, possibly to hold a database connection resource.

A static property is shared between *all* instances of a class, which is the behaviour you appear to be describing.

This type of design will work the way you want:

```
class SQL {
    private $database;

    function connect() {
        $this->datavbase = ....;
    };
}

class WEB extends SQL {
    function __construct(){ $this->connect(params) }
    function __destruct(){ $this->disconnect() }
}

class AUTH extends SQL{
    function __construct(){ $this->connect(params) }
    function __destruct(){ $this->disconnect() }
}
```

This type of design will *not* work the way you want:

```
class SQL {
    private static $database;

    function connect() {
        $this->datavbase = ....;
    };
}

class WEB extends SQL {
    function __construct(){ $this->connect(params) }
    function __destruct(){ $this->disconnect() }
}

class AUTH extends SQL{
    function __construct(){ $this->connect(params) }
    function __destruct(){ $this->disconnect() }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `$this->database` reference when making the SQL calls?

Comment: @Mihai Iorga: In which case you'll need to update your question with a more accurate picture of the code you are using. Your description of the problem is /exactly/ what is expected of static properties.

Comment: that is an accurate picture of the code, it just simply looses the connection from first database and all is set by the second class